# One SQL execution, After a specified time another SQL execution

Tags: mysql

When a record is updated, a field, such as the status is `0`, `500` seconds after,  judge whether the status of this record's status is `0`, if status is `0` will update status into `1`, if it is other, nothing will be done. Others operate may change the status record in the `500` seconds.  How to do it in mysql?

Comment: What have you tried? Please add some code and let us know where you are stuck exactly. We cannot solve the work for you, just point you into the right direction or show you any mistakes you might have done.

Comment: One option would be to store the update time and then calc the difference with the current timestamp:  `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2016-05-30 13:13:55', NOW()) > 500 as status`

Comment: I have had two methods solve this question, but they are not so good. One is use java multi-threading: after the first update, there is a return statement, because this two operate is not under the same transaction，use java timer api or spring timer can do it, but do that, our server may be ruined by memory  overflow and we can't restart the server because of the thread; the Other is use mysql trigger, but there is already a trigger on this table do other thing. My superior want use an mysql event do this thing , I think is is a wrong idea , so I want find an better idea to solve it.

Comment: A db stores and ensures the integrity of data, it doesn't do stuff like you want (at least not well), you should check your db design if you need this. Roland gave you a solution, but I doubt you see that so I'll explain: Don't use 1 and 0, use datetime. Set "1" means: `set status = date_add(now(), Interval -501 second);`, set "0": `set status = now();` Read: `select (timestampdiff(second, status), NOW()) >= 500);` (will be 0 or 1). With casting and a trigger (that changes old.status=0 to now()), you could even use `set status = 0/1`, as long as your read correctly (not recommended though).